# JavaScript Error in IE8 when passing list of images to a function

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have build a function to accept list of images as an arguments. but it throws an error in IE 8
this is code

```
 function MM_reloadPage (init) {  //reloads the window if Nav4 resized
  if (init==true) with (navigator) {if ((appName=="Netscape")&&(parseInt(appVersion)==4)) {
     document.MM_pgW=innerWidth; document.MM_pgH=innerHeight; onresize=MM_reloadPage; 
  }}
  else if (innerWidth!=document.MM_pgW || innerHeight!=document.MM_pgH)       location.reload();
 }
 MM_reloadPage(true);

 </script>
  </head>

  <body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"  onLoad="MM_preloadImages('images/tv_aura_2.jpg','images/tv_aura_4.jpg','images/tv_bk_2.jpg','images/tv_dia_2.jpg','images/tv_gsk_2.jpg','images/tv_gsk_4.jpg','images/tv_hutch_2.jpg','images/tv_mini_2.jpg','images/tv_poppy_2.jpg','images/tv_red_2.jpg','images/tv_island_2.jpg','images/tv_veet_2.jpg')">
```

i havent included all the  html and it throws me an error

```
 The value of the property 'MM_preloadImages' is null or undefined, not a Function 
 object
```

and i cannot figure out a wrong in my js function . can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted is a function called **MM_reloadPage** but you set **MM_preloadImages** for the onload handler...

I don't know though if the onload is supposed to call the function you posted in your question or another one actually called *MM_preloadImages*. In this case, you should post this other function as well...